rancher on docker container not able to clone repos due to Insufficient randomness error
I am trying to run rancher on a docker container in my Synology NAS, but I am betting the following error:
[ERROR] error syncing 'library': handler catalog: Clone failed: Cloning into 'management-state/catalog-cache/380859f1003fe7603cddc6c15b34b7263f1f0deaa92ddcde465811d032ee7078'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.rancher.io/charts/': Insufficient randomness
: exit status 128, requeuing
[ERROR] error syncing 'system-library': handler catalog: Clone failed: Cloning into 'management-state/catalog-cache/a67038d6110101d84b823470950db15b8ab6c06fe4e8895bcae7a337c1a8990d'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.rancher.io/system-charts/': Insufficient randomness
: exit status 128, requeuing
[ERROR] error syncing 'helm3-library': handler catalog: Clone failed: Cloning into 'management-state/catalog-cache/f341cfdfa521a9aa2b993cb34b26bb91b2d173ef1a7df8d41b8921b0e4f82788'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.rancher.io/helm3-charts/': Insufficient randomness
: exit status 128, requeuing
[ERROR] Failed to install system chart fleet-crd: pod cattle-system/helm-operation-6l462 failed, watch closed

If I try to curl the same URL I get same error:
curl https://git.rancher.io/partner-charts/
curl: (35) Insufficient randomness

If I try to clone manually, I get the same error:
git clone https://git.rancher.io/partner-charts/
Cloning into 'partner-charts'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.rancher.io/partner-charts/': Insufficient randomness

Then I tried to mount /dev/urandom from my NAS inside the container, but got the same error.
Have no idea what else to try.
IMPORTANT: I already have a few other containers running in my NAS at the moment. Only rancher is having this issue.
